# Mod_Rewrite rule ignored on Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i got the following RewriteRule in my `.htaccess`-file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*)$ distributor.php?file=$1&params=$2 [L]
```

If i request for example "`www.domain.local/index/id/123`" on my local system via Xampp this works perfectly. It requests distributor.php (which does a simple `var_dump($_GET);` ) and results in the expected output:

```
array
  'file' => string 'index' (length=5)
  'params' => string 'id/123' (length=6)
```

When uploading these files to the server, the rule does not apply. The browser simply outputs the DirectoryIndex file.

I am confused after hours of trying to fix it and would be thankful for any kind of help

Thanks

Update:

if i replace the slash by a dash and use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-(.*)$ distributor.php?file=$1&params=$2 [L]
```

the whole thing works both on my local system and on the server.

Is there anything i need to change to use the slash on the server as well?

Answer (score 0):

Locate your apache configuration file and then add these lines :

```
<Directory /path/to/your/web/application>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

and then if the following line does not exist, write it :

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```